# Can I implement some logic in XML?

Tags: android, xml

I need XML for creating layouts in my Android apps and what I wanted to know is the following. Can I implement some logic in XML? For instance, I wanted to position my text exactly  "(fill_parent - (the width of the image))/2"... something like this.

Comment: No :-) You could check out Relative Layout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Answer (score 4):

you cant do that directly in xml file. if u want to position ur text exactly means just set the positons of the text, check properities of text.

```
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

- main.xml

  contains textview with id textview1.
  like this u can acess the textview of ur xml file..

Answer (score 1):

Not inside the XML. The usual way this is done is to locate the views with `findViewById()` in `onCreate()` after the `setContentView()`, then adjust the relevant properties programmatically.

Edit: after re-reading the example in the question, my advice seems too general (towards modifying any properties on a view). For calculated layout positions you are better achieving these kinds of results with relative layouts or some of the specialized view containers.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you, please, provide some example how this can be done programmatically?

Comment: Here's an example of medium complexity where an application customizes its views after `setContentView()` http://google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#I19AnJAT6GE/trunk/src/com/joulespersecond/seattlebusbot/MultiChoiceActivity.java&l=85